# A the New Year's Day

Tags: articles

Usually "New Year's Day" is treated as a holiday hence it is not used with an article. But I wonder if it's possible to use an article with it?

What do you do on a New Year's Day? (any of them)

What are you going to do on the New Year's Day? (this one)

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

It would not be idiomatic to use articles in either case. The tense of the verb actually carries enough meaning.

> What do you do on New Year's Day. (every year)

> What are you going to do on New Year's Day (this one)

You could use an article, for example

> It was on a New Year's day in the 1980s that I first met Suzie.  (one of them)

> It was on the first New Year's Day of the 1980s that I first met Suzie (Jan 1st 1980)

And (cultural point) many people don't do anything special on New Year's Day. except lie-in. There are more traditions for New Year's *Eve*: Hogmanay.

Comment: OK. But would it be wrong to use the article the way I suggested?

Comment: No,  I've edited to make it more dogmatic.